# How to set start date and end date options in Rails date field dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date

I am using Simple_Form Gem. I have created `date_of_birth:date field` on `Student` model.

So my students form is:

```rb
<%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, label: "Date of Birth" %>
```

When I am going to pick the year in the form, it's just listing year from 2014 to 2024. But I want it should show 1965 - today.

So how can I set start year and end year and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage) state: ***Simple Form** inputs accept the same options as their corresponding input type helper in Rails*:

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :date_of_birth, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 90,
                              end_year: Date.today.year - 12, discard_day: true,
                              order: [:month, :year] %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please, feel free to mark this answer as correct to help other users. Thanks.